# Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.work-queue

Tags: ios, twitter, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

We just pushed our app to the store with upgrading to Fabric (1.2.6.18) and Crashlytics (3.0.9.54).  We are staring to see a crash that is coming from the Crashlytics framework.

Has anyone encountered this issue and have a resolution?

libobjc.A.dylib
objc_msgSend

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.work-queue :: NSOperation 0x1700580c0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000111c5beb8

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. Can you email me at support@fabric.io with your bundle id so I can take a look at the full crash report?

Comment: I did, someone at Fabic support is looking into this.

Comment: Any update? I'm seeing something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by upgrading to the latest Crashlytics and Fabric.  Fabric support was great as usual.